# Pseudocode to C# program

Tags: c#

I am trying to do this task.

I have this table in my database.

```
items_table
------------------
Item_Name | Item ID
A     |  1
B     |  1
C     |  2
D     |  2
E     |  Null
F     |  
G     |  1
H     |  
I     |  Null

Select * from items_table where Item_ID is Null or Item_ID is empty

Loop(while there are items without Item_ID)

Check the count of first Item_ID

if first Item_ID count is less than 8
(update items_table values (current Item_ID ) where Item_Name is current row Item_Name )

otherwise check next Item_ID

If no Item_ID count is less than 8, insert max((Item_ID)+1) where Item_Name is current row Item_Name
```

For the above table this code should do something like this.

E,F,H,I have Group_ID null or empty

Now i have to insert Item_ID for all these items.

First check count of all existing Item_IDs in the table. If any item_ID is used with less than 8 items, than insert that Item_ID for current Item. If no Item_ID has count less than 8, than create a new Item_ID which should be maximum Item_ID + 1.

I am trying to write this but can't figure out how can i loop through rows and count IDs than insert existing one or new one.

```
 private static void FIllGroupID(string connectionString)
        {
            string queryStringNoGroupID =
                "Use Items select * from table_items_shelves where Item_ID is Null or Item_ID = '';";
            SqlCommand GetAllWithoutID = new SqlCommand(queryStringNoGroupID);


            DataTable DataTableAllWithoutID = new DataTable();

            SqlDataAdapter adapterAllWithoutID = new SqlDataAdapter(GetAllWithoutID);

            adapterAllWithoutID.Fill(DataTableAllWithoutID);

            foreach (DataRow row in DataTableAllWithoutID.Rows)
            {

            }

        }
```

How do i loop through existing item_ids and count them. If count is less than 8 than insert the same ID in current row or else create max(item_id)+1 and insert that.

Comment: What part are you finding difficult? Be specific about what you're having a problem with.

Comment: i can't figure out how to loop through group_id and count them and than insert the same/new group_id for each item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now who is going to remove negative votes from the question?

const string str = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Items;Integrated Security=True";
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const string connectionString = str;

```
            DataTable DataTableAllWithoutID = new DataTable();
#if !test
            string queryString = "select * from table_items_shelves;";
            SqlDataAdapter adapterAllWithoutID = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString);
            adapterAllWithoutID.Fill(DataTableAllWithoutID);
            adapterAllWithoutID.Dispose();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            string insertString = "Update table_items_shelves Set Item_ID = @Item_ID where Item_Name = '@key';";
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertString, connection);
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@key", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
#else
            DataTableAllWithoutID.Columns.Add("Item_Name", typeof(string));
            DataTableAllWithoutID.Columns.Add("Item_ID", typeof(object));
            foreach (List<object> row in input)
            {
                DataRow newRow = DataTableAllWithoutID.Rows.Add();
                newRow.ItemArray = row.ToArray();
            }

#endif
            //this code will get empty items
            List<DataRow> nullOrEmpty = DataTableAllWithoutID.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => x.Field<object>("Item_ID") == null)
               .ToList();
            //this creates a dictionary of valid items
            Dictionary<int, List<DataRow>> dict = DataTableAllWithoutID.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<object>("Item_ID") != null)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<object>("Item_ID"), x => x)
                .ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Key), x => (List<DataRow>)x.ToList());
            //create IEnumerator for the null items
            IEnumerator<DataRow> emptyRows = nullOrEmpty.GetEnumerator();
            Boolean noMoreEmptyRows = false;
            if (emptyRows != null)
            {
                foreach (int key in dict.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
                    //get count of items            
                    int count = dict[key].Count;
                    int itemID = (int)key;
                    for (int index = count; count < 8; count++)
                    {
                        if (emptyRows.MoveNext())
                        {
                            //get an item from the null list                  
                            emptyRows.Current["Item_ID"] = itemID;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@Item_ID"].Value = itemID;
                            insertCommand.Parameters["@key"].Value = emptyRows.Current["Item_Name"];
                            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Console.WriteLine("current item ID " + itemID);
                            Console.WriteLine("current count " + count);
                            //Console.ReadKey();
                        }//end if
                        else
                        {
                            noMoreEmptyRows = true;
                            break;
                        }//end else
                    }//end for
                    if (noMoreEmptyRows)
                        break;
                }//end foreach
                if (!noMoreEmptyRows)
                {
                    //increment key to one greater than max value
                    int maxKey = dict.Keys.Max() + 1;
                    int count = 0;
                    while (emptyRows.MoveNext())
                    {
                        //get an item from the null list                  
                        emptyRows.Current["Item_ID"] = maxKey.ToString();
                        insertCommand.Parameters["@Item_ID"].Value = maxKey.ToString();
                        insertCommand.Parameters["@key"].Value = emptyRows.Current["Item_ID"];

                            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                          count++;
                        if (count == 8)
                        {
                            maxKey++;
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//end if
#if test
            foreach (DataRow row in DataTableAllWithoutID.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item_Name : {0}  Item ID :   {1}", 
                    row["Item_Name"], row["Item_ID"]);
            }
#endif

            FIllGroupID(str);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```